# How to load html content(not a page) into a div on button click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I have a form which takes the following code

```
<div class="data" data-id="sports">
<div class="data-inner"></div>
</div>
```

I have a html page that contains A left navigation bar and middle content.
The left Nav contains a List of categories

```
<li class="nav"><?=$sports?></li>
```

and the container has the following div

```
<div class="container">
// js file that supports the iframe to be loaded on my page
   <div class="data" data-id="sports">
<div class="data-inner"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

I used ajax, and tried to print the data it is returning after li is clicked.
As the content being loaded is html, the data(iframe) loads at the nav container instead of loading in .container class

**Update**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function(){
        $('#order li').click(function(){
        $('.container').html('');

        alert($(this).attr("nav"));
        });
        });
</script>
```

So if i click on sports the div section corresponding to **data-id="sports"** will loaded, Same way if Games is clicked **data-id="games"** will be loaded. the div section for games looks like

```
   <div class="data" data-id="games">
    <div class="data-inner"></div>
    </div>
```

Initially i used **iframes**, but as the iframe is not adjusted properly, i was told to work with this code

Hope you got the clear idea now !

I don't have much knowledge in javascript.
Please help

Comment: Could you please include the code that you are currently using? It would really help us to understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: ya sure, i updated my post. Please have a look

Comment: You haven't included the AJAX code.. Where is the code that inserts new HMTL into your document?

Comment: Sorry i was tring with javascript

Answer (score 1):

based on your explanation of what you're trying to do, i'm assuming that this code:

```
<li class="nav"><?=$sports?></li>
```

will be filled with a file name that you want loaded when li is clicked on.

```
e.g.
<li class="nav">baseball.html</li>
<li class="nav">football.html</li>
<li class="nav">soccer.html</li>
```

if this is the case, then this code will load the file into .container when one of those sports (file names) are clicked on

```
$(function(){
    // attach click event to each li element with class "nav"
    $('li .nav').on("click", function(){
        // assuming each li will show the name of a file to load using AJAX, do this
        // load the container div with the file you just clicked on (i.e. $(this) is li ) 
        $('.container').load( $(this).text() );

    });
});
```

Comment: No its not a file name it's a html div section which i want to load on button click. Also the div section will be retrieved from Database

Comment: if its not a file, then you can do this $('.container').html( $(this).html() ); or you can use append()

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of relevant pieces of the puzzle missing from your original question.

But anyway. Try this Javascript code on your page. At the very least it may serve you as a template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    var button = $('a.nav');
    var container = $('div.container').first(); // .first() ensures that only a single div will be used, not many
    var url = 'http://www.yoursite.com/data_from_where_to_load.php';

    button.click(function(){

        var condition = confirm("Load data: Click YES for iframe, click NO for Ajax. ");

        container.html('');

        if(condition){ // load with iframe
            var iframe = $("<iframe />");
            iframe.attr('src',url).appendTo(container);
            iframe.ready(function(){
                alert('if you can see this, probably the iframe just loaded');  
            });

        }else{ // load with Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: url, dataType:'html', complete:function(r){
                    container.html(r.responseText); 
                    alert('done loading via ajax');
                }
            });
        }

    });

});

</script>
```